# react toastr con codigo html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un problema, y es que quiero hacer un boton de confirmación dentro de un toastr, y cuando agrego codigo html al toastr aparece el codigo mas no aparece el botón:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

usando el siguiente codigo:

```
...
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastr";
let container;
<div>
class App extends Component {
...
render(){
..
 return (<div>
    <ToastContainer
              ref={ref => container = ref}
              className="toast-top-right"
            />
      <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() =>
                    container.warning(
                       `¿Desea eliminar "${this.state.todos[i].titulo}" ?  <br /><br /><button type="button" onClick=${this.handleElimitarUno.bind(this,i)} class="btn clear">Sí</button>`,
                       "Alenteción",{
                        "closeButton": true,
                        message: true
                       }
                      )
                    }>Elimitar</button>
    </div>
 );
...
}
export default App;
```

Como puedo hacer para que me muestre el html y no el codigo? que no lo tome como cadena de texto?
Gracias.

Comment: Hola Andres, es recomendable que añadas el código necesario para poder reproducir tu problema, en este caso creo que sería necesario tanto las imports de *App* como el código completo del componente *ToastContainer* donde tienes el problema. Proveer un ejemplo online que poder probar / modificar ayudará aun más. Hay plataformas donde probar *React* como: https://codesandbox.io/ o https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: ¿Qué se supone que hace esta línea? `ref={ref => container = ref}` ¿qué hay en `ref`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citando [la documentación](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-toastr/):

> To display HTML, simply pass JSX instead of strings for title and
> message.

Por lo tanto, cambiando tu string a jsx, quedaría algo como:

```
container.warning(
  <div>
    ¿Desea eliminar {this.state.todos[i].titulo} ?
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={this.handleElimitarUno.bind(this, i)}
      className="btn clear"
    >
      Sí
    </button>
  </div>,
  'Alenteción',
  {
    closeButton: true,
    message: true,
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

A primera vista tu problema es este:

```
return (
    <ToastContainer
              ref={ref => container = ref}
              className="toast-top-right"
            />
      <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() =>
                    container.warning(
                       `¿Desea eliminar "${this.state.todos[i].titulo}" ?  <br /><br /><button type="button" onClick=${this.handleElimitarUno.bind(this,i)} class="btn clear">Sí</button>`,
                       "Alenteción",{
                        "closeButton": true,
                        message: true
                       }
                      )
                    }>Elimitar</button>
    </div>
 );
```

Debes "encerrar todo el código JSX dentro de una etiqueta JSX, por ejemplo un `div` o fragment. Veo que cierras el código con un `div` pero no lo abres, así puedes probar:

```
return (
    <div>
        <ToastContainer
              ref={ref => container = ref}
              className="toast-top-right"
            />
      <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() =>
                    container.warning(
                       `¿Desea eliminar "${this.state.todos[i].titulo}" ?  <br /><br /><button type="button" onClick=${this.handleElimitarUno.bind(this,i)} class="btn clear">Sí</button>`,
                       "Alenteción",{
                        "closeButton": true,
                        message: true
                       }
                      )
                    }>Elimitar</button>
    <div/>
 );
```

Comment: Ya, fue un error a la hora de hacer la publicación, ya quedó editado